# How to start a virtual machine on Azure with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

I am using the Azure node.js SDK. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/

Strangely I cannot find documentation for starting a virtual machine on Azure using the node.js SDK.

I need a clear example of how to launch an Azure virtual machine using the node.js SDK.

Also I need reference documentation that specifies all the optional parameters for launching a Virtual Machine using the node.js SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one example.

```js
var startVirtualMachine = async function(resourceGroup, vmName){
    try {
        let credential = await msRestAzure.loginWithServicePrincipalSecret(process.env.AZURE_CLIENT_ID, process.env.AZURE_APPLICATION_SECRET, process.env.AZURE_TENANT);
        computeClient = new ComputeManagementClient(credential, process.env.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID);
        await computeClient.virtualMachines.start(resourceGroup, vmName);
        return true;
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460799.aspx) to manage your VM. To start a VM, it's [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj157189.aspx). There is no options though.

You can then use [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) for example to issue your POST request.

Answer (score 0):

As I known, you can use [the Virtual Machine REST API of Azure Resource Management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163647.aspx) to start your VM with the parameters `subscription-Id`, `resource-group-name` & `vm-name`, please move to the doc https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt163628.aspx to know the start API for Azure VM.

> Note: the `api-version` required is `2015-06-15`

The API with POST request need to be authenticated via set up request header `Authorization: Bearer <access token>`.

For requesting access token, you can refer to the offical sample code https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs/blob/master/sample/client-credentials-sample.js to get the token from the code `tokenResponse.accessToken`.

Or you can use the function [`VirtualMachineOperations.start`](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-node/azure-arm-compute/latest/VirtualMachineOperations-VirtualMachineOperations.html#start) of the node package `azure-arm-compute` to start VM with the same parameters above, please refer to the doc http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-node/azure-arm-compute/latest/.